# Testing a function which calls a non-constant function

Tags: solidity, transactions, truffle, testrpc, events

I have a non-constant function inside a contract:

```
contract InnerContract {
    event Event(uint256);

    function func(uint256 val) external returns (uint256) {
        Event(val);
        return val;
    }
}
```

It is invoked from a function inside another contract:

```
import './InnerContract.sol';

contract OuterContract {
    InnerContract pInnerContract;

    function func(uint256 val) external returns (uint256) {
        return pInnerContract.func(val) + 1;
    }
}
```

I am trying to test it in truffle via the following script:

```
contract('Test', () => {
    let hInnerContract;
    let hOuterContract;

    before(async () => {
        hInnerContract = await artifacts.require("InnerContract.sol").new();
        hOuterContract = await artifacts.require("OuterContract.sol").new();
    });

    describe('test:', async () => {
        let input = 1;
        it(`expected output = ${input + 1}`, async () => {
            try {
                let hash = await hOuterContract.func(input);
                let output = Number(hash.receipt.logs[0].data);
                assert(output == input + 1, `actual output = ${output}`);
            }
            catch (error) {
                assert(false, error.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

However, the problem is with `hash.receipt.logs[0].data`.

It contains the value inside the `event` generated in the `InnerContract` function.

I've figured that I should generate an `event` also in the `OuterContract` function:

```
contract OuterContract {
    event Event(uint256);
    InnerContract pInnerContract;

    function func(uint256 val) external returns (uint256) {
        uint256 val2 = pInnerContract.func(val) + 1;
        Event(val2);
        return val2;
    }
}
```

But when I do this, I get the following exception in truffle:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined
at C:\Users\...\cli.bundled.js:316118:19
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at C:\Users\...\cli.bundled.js:316114:32
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at Object.decodeLogs (C:\Users\...\cli.bundled.js:316067:19)
at Object.callback (C:\Users\...\cli.bundled.js:316195:35)
at C:\Users\...\cli.bundled.js:37985:25
at C:\Users\...\cli.bundled.js:328869:9
at C:\Users\...\cli.bundled.js:324536:9
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\...\cli.bundled.js:327565:7)
```

BTW, before this exception occurs, truffle indicates that both events have indeed been emitted:

```
Events emitted during test:
---------------------------

Event(: 1)
Event(: 2)

---------------------------
```

Can you please explain what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined` exception can be resolved by "naming" the anonymous variable inside each one of the events.

In other words, changing every occurrence of this:

```
event Event(uint256);
```

To something like this:

```
event Event(uint256 x);
```

For some reason, the "anonymous event" works only as long as a single event is emitted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you have an **Internal Contract** with a function name `func` simply returns a value and an **External contract** that overrides the same function. The `func` of outer contract calls the `func` of Inner contract and adds 1 to the returned value.

Deploy the **Inner Contract**

```
contract InnerContract {
    function func(uint256 val) external returns (uint256) {
        return val;
    }
}
```

Let the address of Inner contract be: `0xdc04977a2078c8ffdf086d618d1f961b6c546222`.

Deploy the **Outer Contract** with following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
contract InnerContract {
    function func(uint256 val) external returns (uint256) {
    }
}

contract OuterContract is InnerContract{
    InnerContract pInnerContract = InnerContract(0xdc04977a2078c8ffdf086d618d1f961b6c546222);
   function func(uint256 val) external returns (uint256) {
        return  pInnerContract.func(val) + 1;
    }
}
```

Now when you cal `func_outer` with value 1. The return value is 2.

Comment: "overrides the same function" - this is wrong, I am not overriding anything here. It's simply a (non-constant) function which calls a non-constant function. And I am unable to test the outer function with `truffle test`, due to some weird exception in truffle.

Comment: Yeah, that was my bad. Please check updates.

Comment: I don't have a problem calling the outer function. I have a problem invoking it from the JS script (a part of my question which you seem to have completely ignored), and retrieving its returned value - something which can be done only via events (another part of my question which you have not referred to).